# Selecting records from a particular time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

I want to select records from SQL server table 'employeelogdetails' which has field 'logintime' (which registers time in GMT when employee swipes the access card while entering or leaving office) which is datetime datetype. Now I want to select records say from yesterday 17 October 2012, 14:00 GMT

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEELOGDETAILS WHERE LOGINTIME > ' ..........' LOGINTIME DESC
```

Don't know how to go forward guys, have been trying this for a while

Help me out

Comment: You just need to put your desired date into the '...'  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you records from the 17th after 14:00 for the rest of the day.  I'm not certain what time window you are looking for though, so this may need slight adjustment.

```
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeLogDetails AS eld
WHERE eld.LoginTime > '2012-10-17 14:00:00'
   AND eld.LoginTime < '2012-10-18'
ORDER BY eld.LoginTime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select * from EmployeeLogDetails where LoginTime between '17/10/2012' and Now();
```

Comment: I need to specify time as well mate

Comment: Yes.. Here you can specify the time along with the date

Comment: Yes..So sorry..  Currently im working in MySql.. I just want to give idea about "between".

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEELOGDETAILS WHERE 
   LOGINTIME > CONVERT(DateTime,'2012/10/17 14:00:00') ORDER BY LOGINTIME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work this way:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeLogDetails  
WHERE LoginTime BETWEEN ('20121017 9:00:00.000' AND '20121018 3:37:00.000') 
ORDER BY LoginTime DESC;
```

Thank you all for the responses